# how to use gradle command to generate proper war file

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, jboss, apache-axis

Good day,

Base on this page, https://www.eclipse.org/webtools/community/tutorials/TopDownAxis2WebService/td_tutorial.html,
I am using eclipse to create a Top Down java bean web service, by using Axis2 runtime.

The different of mine, is I am using `Red Hat JBoss EAP` as my server.

After done the thing, I am now want to generate the war file and deploy in another Red Hat JBoss server. I can successfully generate the war file by right click on the project in my eclipse and export it as war, and the war file can successfully deploy into Jnoss server and the service can up successfully.

In the other way, I would like to try to use `gradle` command to generate the war file, instead of using eclipse to generate. Thus I run `gradle clean build` command to generate the war file. Yes, the war file can be generated but the file size lesser 10MB if compare with the one I generate throw eclipse.

And the war generate by gradle command, I will hit 404 when I view the service after I deployed into my Jboss server.

I extract both the war to compare, and found that the one using command is lack of the `axis2-web` library folder.
The following is my screen shot:

1. eclipse generated war file and with the 3 folders after I extract the war:
   [image]
2. `gradle clean build` generated war file and with the 2 folders after I extract the war:
   [image]

As you can see, the one generate by gradle command, lack of the `axis2-web` library folder, thus I believe this is why it can be access successfully after deployed.

and the following is my `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName = "EAIDelegateBeanServiceSkeleton"

repositories { 
    mavenCentral() 
    maven {
        url "https://packages.confluent.io/maven"
    }
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    compile "com.google.guava:guava:17.0"
    compile 'com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1'
    compile 'org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:3.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    compile 'io.confluent:kafka-json-serializer:6.2.0'
    compile "org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka:2.6.13"
    compile "org.springframework:spring-web:5.2.19.RELEASE"
    testImplementation "junit:junit:4.12"
}
```

I would like to ask for help on how can I configure so that I can generate the correct war file by using `gradle` command.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the solution is configure the webContent/web-inf under war in `build.gradle`:

```
war {
    webInf { from 'WebContent/WEB-INF' }
}
```